# Why $Y=F(x)^{G(x)}$ defined for F(x)>0?

Tags: functions

During my lecture, my maths teacher said that "F(X) raised to power G(x) defined for F(x)>0"

**Attempt**: this attempt was suggested by one my class mate:

Suppose $Y=F(x)^{G(x)}$ take log both side and differentiate then you will get $Log(F(x))$ which is only defined for F(x)>0

**Question** : it doesn't means that if we can't differentiate a function then it doesn't exist so my question is why $Y=F(x)^{G(x)}$ is defined for F(x)>0

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos i have write attempt and also edit it again... thanks you

Comment: How do you define, say, $(-1)^{\sqrt2}$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos , oh i don't able to think about this counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking why it is defined for $F(x)>0$, or are you asking why it isn't defined for $F(x)\le0$?

It is defined for $F(x)>0$ as $e^{G(x)\log F(x)}$, as $\log F(x)$ is defined for $F(x)>0$.

It isn't defined for $F(x)=0$ because, for example, $0^{-1}$ is not a real number.

It isn't defined for $F(x)<0$ because, for example, $(-1)^{\pi}$ isn't defined. Well you can define $(-1)^{\pi}$, but you have to use the complex logarithm function, and that involves choosing a branch of that function, and that's too hard to deal with at an introductory level.